# Javascript regular exp not working correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote this JS code for validating the password must not contain the (!) char.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sr8xm/

```
var pattern = /[A-Za-z0-9.#&@_-]{6,20}/;

$("#pwd").blur(function(){
        pwd = $(this).val();
        if(!pattern.test(pwd)){
            alert('Please enter valid new password.');      
            return false;
        }
});
```

but this returns true if someone type ! char after 6 chars ??
any idea what going wrong in this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong -- what you observe is as per what you've _instructed_.

Comment: Use anchors. `^` and `$`.  Voting to close as _typo_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor your regex:

```
var pattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9.#&@_-]{6,20}$ /;
```

You could also reduce it to:

```
var pattern = /^[\w.#&@-]{6,20}$/;
```

Comment: Thanks the second way is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

`/[A-Za-z0-9.#&@_-]{6,20}/` can match the middle part of the password string. For example it matches "!mypassword!" and return true. You'd use `^` (matches the beginning of the string) and `$` (matches the end of the string) like `/^[A-Za-z0-9.#&@_-]{6,20}$/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict your chosen characters, you can use another expression which will check presence of restricted characters. But anchoring regex is also quick solution for your prob

```
    var pattern = /[A-Za-z0-9.#&@_-]{6,20}/g;
    var restrictedChar =/[!]+/g;  // Add more character here which u want to restrict
    var pwd = $("#pwd").val();

    if(!pattern.test(pwd) || restrictedChar.test(pwd)){
        alert('Please enter valid new password.');      
        return false;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sr8xm/5/)